# CV2 throwing erros when compiled into EXE, not when self compiled

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am currently working on a Video to Ascii converter (basicly a image to ascii converter that can do video playback), and this works perfectly when I run as a .py file, but once i use pyinstaller to convert it into a exe file, it no longer works, and it throws this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (681) CvCapture_MSMF::initStream Failed to set mediaType (stream 0, (0x0 @ 1) MFVideoFormat_RGB24(unsupported media type)
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am using CV2 to import the videofiles, and i use pyautogui for some basic ui, and i use easygui to get a file explorer (to choose file)

Let me know if you need to see the code

Answer (score 0):

copy `opencv_video_ffmpeg412_64.dll` from `Anaconda3\envs\your_env_name\Lib\site-packages\cv2` to the dir where exe file lies.